# Is there a way to import both type of contact types together (Individual and Organisation)?

Tags: extension, import, data-import

I am looking for a solution where I can just do importing contact together for both individual and organisation contact types. Please assist me.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any way to mix up different contact types on import, who have different fields from each other.